# Is it possible to make only one of my collapsible open at a time?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using rows of collapsibles on top of one another. I want to make my site look more professional, so my goal is to make it so only one collapsible can be opened at a time. Here is the JavaScript I am using currently:

```js
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
          content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          content.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
    }
```

Here is the html for the collapsible:

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible"></button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Is there any way I can get it so only one collapsible can open at a time?

Comment: Just loop through all of the elements in `coll` each click and remove the `active` class from them unless they're the one being clicked, then you would add it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to make it close the other open rows.

Here is a test: https://jsfiddle.net/up3t4129/

One thing you need to understand is that make sure to loop through all other open ones, and just close them, that way you can get the result of what you wanting.

I made some comment on the code, so you can understand it easier.

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    // here we are gonna loop through the elements
    for(item of coll){
      // and remove .active class on the button
      item.classList.remove("active");

      // here we are checking the next element and making it don't display
      item.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
    }
      
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```